# Does the game that Chewie plays with R2-D2 have a name?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In Episode IV, on the way to Alderaan aboard the Millennium Falcon, we see Chewbacca playing (and losing) a chess-like game with R2-D2. Does this game have a name? Do we know what its rules are?

[image]

Comment: I always called it "Space Chess."

Comment: "Holo-Chess" was the more common name I heard growing up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The name of the game is [Dejarik](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dejarik) as confirmed both by Wookieepedia and my [Haynes Corellian YT-1300 Manual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7CKKm-HMTA).

I am unaware of any official rules but of course fans have created [their own unofficial rules to the game](http://zeelay.free.fr/star-wars-artisanal/)

Comment: That Haynes guide looks awesome. It doesn't appear technical enough, needs more diagrams and instructions!